# Az CLI query not displaying all columns properly

Tags: azure, jmespath, azure-cli2

I have run the command

```sh
az account list locations --output table
```

and it displays me three columns  with values in them: `DisplayName`, `Name`, `RegionalDisplayName`.
Now I want to view only two columns e.g `Name` and `RegionalDisplayName`. So I run the command attached in the screenshot and it shows me only one column. Any idea what is the correct way to display the two columns with the query command?

[image: az account with JMESPath query]

Comment: Please do not use images for something that can be represented as code blocks. This include code, output, errors, etc. Rather paste it in your question in code blocks right away. See [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the only mistake in your query is "case sensitive names"
When you are trying to query JSON output, in the `--query` parameter we should provide the exact name of the Json array value name.

Your complete query will be (see the `name` instead of `Name` and the `regionalDisplayName`)

```sh
az account list-locations --query "[].{name: name, region: regionalDisplayName}" --output table
```

For more, check out the answer posted here and detailed explanation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/302069/az-cli-not-showing-correct-output.html?childToView=302127#answer-302127

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like:

```
az account list-locations --output table  --query '[].{Name:name,DisplayName:displayName}'
```

This is the output I am getting (partial) when I run the above command:

```
Name                DisplayName
------------------  --------------------
eastasia            East Asia
southeastasia       Southeast Asia
centralus           Central US
eastus              East US
eastus2             East US 2
westus              West US
northcentralus      North Central US
southcentralus      South Central US
```

I'm using version 2.8 of az CLI.

Answer (score 0):

In JMESPath, when using [filters and multiselect hashes](https://jmespath.org/examples.html#filters-and-multiselect-hashes), you are recreating JSON objects in a key/value way.

So when you are doing something like

```
[*].{foo: bar}
```

Then, `foo` is your new key, it is whatever your like it to be.
And `bar` is a value that, if not inside quotes, should be an existing value in your source JSON.

So, in your case, you just inverted what should be the key and the value, since you have a key `Name` and a key `RegionalDisplayName` in your source JSON.

So you have to do:

```sh
az account list-locations --query "[].{name: name, region: regionalDisplayName}" --output table
```

In order to have the two columns containing what you expect and that would be have the title `name` and `region` respectively.

Comment: The command : az account list-locations --query "[].{name: Name, region: RegionalDisplayName}" --output table , doesn't display anything and brings me back to the prompt again